# step interpolation

Tags: mariadb, sequence

My data:

```
+------------+-------+
|    date    | value |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-12-01 |   10  |
| 2018-12-09 |   15  |
| 2018-12-17 |   12  |
+------------+-------+
```

My goal:

```
+------------+-------+
|    date    | value |
+------------+-------+
| 2018-12-01 |   10  |
| 2018-12-02 |   10  |
| 2018-12-03 |   10  |
| 2018-12-04 |   10  |
| 2018-12-05 |   10  |
| 2018-12-06 |   10  |
| 2018-12-07 |   10  |
| 2018-12-08 |   10  |
| 2018-12-09 |   15  |
| 2018-12-10 |   15  |
| 2018-12-11 |   15  |
| 2018-12-12 |   15  |
| 2018-12-13 |   15  |
| 2018-12-14 |   15  |
| 2018-12-15 |   15  |
| 2018-12-16 |   15  |
| 2018-12-17 |   12  |
| 2018-12-18 |   12  |
| 2018-12-19 |   12  |
| 2018-12-20 |   12  |
| 2018-12-21 |   12  |
+------------+-------+
```

Ideally I'd like to provide the start and end dates of the full range in the query, or they could range from the date of the oldest value up to the day of the query.

I've tried with [MariaDB sequence engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/), successfully generating the dates, but no success for the values.

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DAYS(CURDATE())` is 737410.  Let's back up at least a year from that, and go forward a year or so, build a sequence for all those days:

```
seq_737000_to_738000
```

Now, you want to start at `2018-12-01` and go to `CURDATE()`?

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(seq) AS a_day FROM seq_737000_to_738000
    WHERE seq BETWEEN TO_DAYS("2018-12-01") AND CURDATE();
```

That will give you "2018-12-01", "2018-12-02", ... through today.  So that's the left column.

You could replace `TO_DAYS("2018-12-01")` with `( SELECT MIN(date) FROM mydata )`.  (Yes, you will need extra parentheses.)

To get the right column,

```
SET @value := 0;   -- something to get it started (may be unnecessary?)
SELECT  dates.a_day  AS 'Date',
        @value := IF(dates.a_day = m.date, m.value, @value) AS 'Value'
    FROM ( SELECT FROM_DAYS(seq) AS a_day ... ) AS dates  -- see above
    JOIN mydata AS m
    ORDER BY dates.a_day
```

The `IF(...)` either picks up the next `value` from your table or hangs onto the old value.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work with pagination...

Comment: @Samuel - Start a new Question with your code that "doesn't work with pagination".  Are you using `OFFSET`?  Consider "remembering where you left off".

Comment: problem lies in setting the initial value for the page, as you could have to start with an already interpolated value. Unfortunately, this solution only works when you start from 0. But I'm not looking for the ultimate solution here. Just mentioning, as I found out while going to the next page in phpMyAdmin.